# Ionic Android - Music player stops working after few minutes

Tags: android, ionic-framework, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

Although there are many tutorials on building music players, such as [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_rKawKDq58&ab_channel=SimonGrimm) one, none are currently working for android when the phone is locked. I've tried [Native Audio](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio) with [Media Session](https://github.com/daubit/capacitor-media-session) to
have a foreground service that plays the audio and has Audio Controls in the notification bar. [HERE](https://github.com/ArielAleksandrus/bible-audio) is my Ionic project.

The audio plays correctly, buttons work fine, and progress bar is updated, but check out this method inside my **smart-audio.service.ts**

```
setMediaSessionPosition() {
    if(this.mediaProgressTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.mediaProgressTimeout);
    }

    this.position().then(secs => {
      if(this.active && this.active.status == "playing") {
        let duration = this.active.mediaObj.getDuration();
        if(!isNaN(duration)) {
          this.ending = duration - secs < 5;
          MediaSession.setPositionState({
            duration: duration,
            playbackRate: 1,
            position: secs
          });
        }
      }
    });
    this.mediaProgressTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if(this.active)
        this.setMediaSessionPosition();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

As you can see, this method recursively calls itself every 1 second to update the status bar. **When I lock my phone**, it still works for a few minutes, but then instead of 1 second, it calls itself after 2 seconds, 3 seconds, then it is never called again, as if my app's process was put on a **permanent sleep**.

When that happens, not only the progress bar stops being updated, but also the media buttons (Previous track, Next track, Pause) are **unresponsive**. The audio is played until it ends, but the next track is never played because my app is asleep. Even with Wakelocks being requested everytime that timeout method is called.

I've tried Wakelocks, I've checked the android permissions on Foreground Service, Background Service, everything, I've checked the broadcast receiver on android manifest for those media buttons, and everything seems correct.

My app, just like Spotify, needs to play audio indefinately even with the phone locked. Why on Earth is my app being put to sleep even with foreground service and how can I prevent it?

P.S.: 90% of Ionic's plugins had their last commit 4 years ago or more. Is Ionic dead?

Comment: Well i'm not answering It because there are many Approaches. Ionic are not dead, but ionic plays well with active and objective apps whose into foreground users interecrs with and achieve results e Go on. But with bg ionic hás some libs but (myself Op never plays well) so Its hard to acheive what you wants. React Native by other hand can help you write more OS Native code and hit what you want. Remember this is my stand alone approach